# In the situation that i have a countably generated \sigma -algebra, can i assume the generator to have the shape of an algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Or, differently formulated: can a countable generator be completed to an algebra by countable set operations, while still generating the same sigma-alegbra?
since the generator not necessarily has a defined structure it's hard to imagine this should be possible. On the other hand i can't seem to find a counterexample. One idea was to find out whether there is a minimal countable generator and then fill it up with countable missing sets. The other is the converse, find a maximal countable generator and proof the algebra properties. In the first case, there are restrictions to when a minimal generator exists. Sadly i cannot afford those boundaries. In the second case, i have absolutely no idea how to find out whether finite intersections/unions or complements are included in the set, whereas if i have a maximal generator (in case of existence, I haven't found anything confirming or denying this) i have automatically the base set in the generator. Are there any ideas out there, that could help?

Comment: Yes, that is always possible. And please use correct capitalization to improve readability.

Comment: Can you give the argument, because, to me a generator does not have any apparent structure. Why/how can we see this structure is already there to be chosen? I still do not understand.

Comment: Let (E, F) be my measure space and D my countable generator. Now if I consider D as a  generator of an algebra instead of a sigma-algebra, is it still countable and will the sigma algebra generated by this algebra still generate F? The countability should be result of only letting finite operations resolve on a countable set. And since the generated algebra is a subset of the sigma algebra it generates it, right?

Comment: What you need to know is that the familyof finite subsets of a countable set is countable and that the union of countably many families of countable sets is again countable. So start with the countable family C_0 and define recursively $C_{n+1}$ as the family that contains all sets in $C_n$ all complements of elements of $C_n$, and all finite unions of elements of $C_n$. Then $C=\bigcup_{n=0}^n C_n$ is the smallest algebra containing $C_0$. Yu can verify that, verify that $C$ is countable since each $C_n$ is by induction, and similarly that $C\subseteq \sigma(C_0)=\sigma(C)$.

Comment: Thanks, I see why induction does the trick. I was trying another way,i.e. finding a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$ and did not consider this much easier path.